# Adding a contact form on each page

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, interface, contact-us

I was visiting a friends' web page and realized that he has added contact form on each page. Actually I did not like it; but he told me he does want to catch every possibility that a visitor wants to fill the form.

I wonder what your idea would be on adding a contact page to every page sidebar. Does this look cheesy? Also this is not that good on tracking aspects, where he cannot analyze if someone really wants to contact and clicks the contact-us page.

Thank you for your ideas in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done on several websites before (I can't remember any at the moment) and on each one, the form was maybe at most *300px x 200px in the footer*. Because it's in the footer, it's hardly in the way of the normal user's flow, and it's easy to access.

However, if I remember, these sites were only corporations, and it sounds like this is your friend's personal site. If someone really wanted to contact just one person, I believe one form and an email or phone is sufficient. How many questions or messages could he get in comparison to a corporation?

He could easily determine if the contact sent from the contact page or another form by simply adding those details in behind the scenes. I wouldn't say it's hard to track at all.